# Deserialization with JSON.NET (DataSet type is ignored)

Tags: json, json.net

I have the following class...

```
[JsonObject]
    public class Response
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public RequestStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public String StatusMessage { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public Dictionary<String,String> response { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public DataSet dataResponse { get; set; }
        public Response()
        {
            StatusMessage = String.Empty;
            response = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dataResponse = new DataSet();
        }

    }
```

After serialization with JSON.NET using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject)` I get the following beautiful JSON string (just an example):

```
{"StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"Succeed.","response":{},"dataResponse":{"Table":[{"LabelID":355,"ProductID":1005,"InternalPN":"111INT","Description":"Produs2","WorkOrderSerialNumber":"0000000005","LabelNumber":1,"BarCode":"P000000000500001","Pallet":true,"LabelStatusID":1,"StatusName":"Printed","UserIDAddStatus":1004,"UserNameAddStatus":"test1","DataAddStatus":"2017-03-15T18:42:27.01","IsValidScan":false}]}}
```

Well, the problem comes when it's time to recreate the original object using
 `myObject =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json)`

in the `DataSet` property `dataResponse` there is no data loaded. All the other properties are ok except this. There is no error, no nothing.

Is there any solution to recreate the original object using JSON.NET?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: DataSet.Tables property is not directly  assignable. So JSON deserializer can not set that property of dataset. So at the best you will get is empty data set but tables property of it will be null or empty collection.

Comment: I found the issue. It's all about the target Framework. I'm currently develop for MonoAndroid\v1.0 framework and seams that DataSet from Mono is not the same as DataSet from .NETFramework. It works fine for .NETFramework 4.5 but not also for MonoAndoid. So I have to develop my own deserializer.